# Getting location null with fused location provider getLastLocation

Tags: android, location-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using googleApiClient with LocationServices api to get the location.

I am able to get last location if In phone settings wifi & mobile network location is checked.

But If I unchecked the wifi & mobile network location. It does not provide any location. while GPS Settings in checked in both cases.

**My question :-** Google's new api can get location from gps or not. ?

Answer (score 0):

> Google's new api can get location from gps or not. ?

**may be yes.**

But as per Google

> The Google API Client provides a common entry point to all the Google Play services and manages the network connection between the user's device and each Google service.

We must have to provide the network access either wifi or mobile-data for getting the actual location's co-ordinate.